# how to not duplicate httpBackend code in angular tests?

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine, httpbackend

I have some services that call for data while loading.

so my tests fail because there are unexpected calls that I need to specify in `$httpBackend`.

this causes a lot of duplicate code in my tests.

part of my attempts to reduce the duplicated code, I decided to add `$rootScope.test` flag, and if this flag is on those services do not load the data but still I need to duplicate `$rootScope.test=true` all over the tests.

Is there a way to do this properly in angular tests?

Here is some code

```
   $httpBackend.expectGET('/backend/system/translations/en.json').respond({'angularjs': 'cool'});
   $httpBackend.expectGET('/backend/system/translations/he.json').respond({'angularjs': 'cool'});
   $httpBackend.expectGET('/backend/system/translations/ru.json').respond({'angularjs': 'cool'});
   $httpBackend.expectGET('/backend/system/translations/ar.json').respond({'angularjs': 'cool'});
   $httpBackend.expectGET('/translations/general.json').respond({'angularjs': 'cool'});
    i18n = $filter('i18n');
```

Every directive I have with some translation support require these statements per language.

Comment: Can you put some code ? Basically, you can set regular expression in $httpBackEnd for passThrough a complete path of tempates or data...

Comment: @benek please see code added to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To handle every url in the same way with just one statement try sth like this:

```
$httpBackend.expectGET(function(url){
  return true;
}).respond({'angularjs': 'cool'});
```

From [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend) first argument of expectGET is:

> HTTP url or function that receives the url and returns true if the url
>   match the current definition.

If you want to define response to just translation urls, try sth like this:

```
$httpBackend.expectGET(function(url){
   return url.lastIndexOf("/backend/system/translations/", 0) === 0;
}).respond({'angularjs': 'cool'});
```

Also, are you sure that you need to use `expectGET()` instead of `whenGET()`? If you don't care whether given urls were called or not, how many times and in which order and you just want to define responses, then when... methods are the way to go:

See: "Request Expectations vs Backend Definitions" section of the mentioned doc page.

> Backend definitions allow you to define a fake backend for your
>   application which doesn't assert if a particular request was made or
>   not, it just returns a trained response if a request is made. The test
>   will pass whether or not the request gets made during testing.

Comment: when is the answer for me. My full solution is to have a module declared in a different file filled with 'when'. When I want to assert backend calls I do not include that module in angular.. thanks very much.